# How to download and cache a new image in each cell using Kingfisher library swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Kingfisher only downloads and caches the image once and uses that same on in each cell and doesn't download a new one. I've tried using the .ForceRefresh option but it doesn't work.

The code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")
    cell.imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(imageURL!)


    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can use `KingfisherManager.sharedManager.cache.removeImageForKey(imageURL)` or `KingfisherManager.sharedManager.cache.clearMemoryCache()` and `KingfisherManager.sharedManager.cache.clearDiskCache()` if you want to clear everything.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with Kingfisher, I've come to the conclusion that the problem is not at all about the cache. `.ForceRefresh` is working properly, and even using separate cache locations will not fix the issue.

I think that the problem lies in the way unsplash deals with requests to its `"https://source.unsplash.com/random"` endpoint. Because all the requests from Kingfisher fire at pretty much the same time, unsplash delivers the same photo to all of your requests (probably an optimization on their end).

You can get a little more random by making requests to

`NSURL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random?page=" + String(indexPath.row))`

(which maybe refers to an upcoming random photo?), but even with that I've noticed that some photos appear twice sometimes. As far as I can tell, this is the most successful approach.

Fortunately, at least this way you still get to take advantage of Kingfisher's caching.